# Reading multiple values from Firebase Database on Android

Tags: android, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read some values from each child in my Firebase Database and then store them in an Array List.

First of all, I created a variable outside so it could be accessed by any method.

```
    ArrayList<LatLng> latlngs = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then on onCreate method, I did this

```
 mLocationDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                LocationCurrent post = dsp.getValue(LocationCurrent.class);
                Double latitude = Double.parseDouble(post.getLatitude());
                Double longitude = Double.parseDouble(post.getLongitude());
                currentLocationLatLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                latlngs.add(currentLocationLatLng);

                Log.i("LAT LONGS IN", String.valueOf(latlngs));

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Logging there works fine, I get to see all LatLong values. But when I call the same log inside onCreate but outside the method call above I get an empty array.

```
Log.i("LAT LONGS OUT", String.valueOf(latlngs));
```

What is the problem and what is the best fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

When using addListenerForSingleValueEvent, onDataChange callback is called asynchronously some time in the future. If you try to log something right after the next line, the code inside onDataChange callback may still not be executed. There is no fix for it, it was simply not initialized at the moment. If you want to work with the data, make sure you wait until onDataChange callback is fired.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have been spending way to much time on this just to find out that there is no fix. So how could I work with the data I get? What do you mean to wait until onDataChange callback is fired?

Comment: When you call mLocationDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...) the code inside the onDataChange(...) method will be executed some time in the future. Meaning in the next second or maybe in 30seconds. Basically anything you need to do with data you are getting from firebase, do it in onDataChange method.